# How to write and use a java agent for Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I am completely new to Lotus Java Agent.
Kindly help me how can i write a java agent in eclipse and use that agent in other classes.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you will need to do is to copy the Notes.jar file into your java project,(found in any Notes client installation), add it as an external jar.

Then create a java agent (in Lotus Notes), copy that initial boilerplate code out of Domino Designer, and into a new class in eclipse, (and call it JavaAgent.java). You should be able to get started.

For more details [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/notes-eclipse/) IBM developerworks article covers it quite well.

Answer (score 0):

[Mikkel Heisterberg](http://lekkimworld.com/) has a [series of articles](http://lekkimworld.com/2006/06/12/1150089700490.html) that go through the ins and outs of this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/06082009125716AMWEB7TU.htm